# How to display MySQL database entries in HTML table using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I have successfully displayed the MySQL table in HTML data table, however, there is a bug that makes the display incorrect.

see image:

[image: Bug Display]

[image: Searching datatable]

this is the code behind the display.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                loadAccountList();
        });

        function loadAccountList() {

            $.ajax({
                /*url: "../srtdash/php_functions/account_list.php",
                type: "POST", 
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: {}, //this is data you send to your server*/
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../srtdash/php_functions/account_list.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {},
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(res)
                {   
                        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

                                var lst;

                                if (res[i]['status'] == 1 ){
                                    lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-primary">Pending</a></h4>';
                                }else if (res[i]['status'] == 2 ){
                                    lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-secondary">For Approval</a></h4>';
                                }else if (res[i]['status'] == 3 ) {
                                    lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-success">For CAD</a></h4>';
                                }else if (res[i]['status'] == 4 ){
                                    lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-danger">For Appraisal</a></h4>';
                                }else if (res[i]['status'] == 5 ){
                                    lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-info">Release</a></h4>';
                                }

                          $('#tableBody').append('<tr><td hidden>' + res[i]['account_id'] 
                            + '</td><td>' + res[i]['bvcsi_control'] 
                            + '</td><td>' + res[i]['account_name'] 
                            + '</td><td>' + res[i]['date_inspection'] 
                            + '</td><td>' + res[i]['date_report'] 
                            + '</td><td>' + res[i]['act_useof_prop'] 
                            + '</td><td>' + res[i]['landmark']
                            + '</td><td>' + res[i]['reg_owner']     
                            + '</td><td>' + lst
                            + '</td></tr>')
                        }
                }       
            });
    }
```

HTML:

```
                    <div class="data-tables">
                        <table id="dataTable" class="text-center" >
                            <thead class="bg-light text-capitalize">
                                <tr>
                                    <th hidden>User ID</th>
                                    <th>Control No.</th>
                                    <th>Account Name</th>
                                    <th>Date Inspection</th>
                                    <th>Date of Report</th>
                                    <th>Actual Use</th>
                                    <th>Landmark</th>
                                    <th>Registered Owner</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tableBody">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

And also the error, when I search using the textbox in datatable is not filtering the table it only states that `No data available in table`

Comment: @Emma Ok Ma'am. I'll do it.

Comment: @Emma Hi Ma'am. I dont have enough reputations that's why i cannot insert an image.

Comment: @Emma Hi again Ma'am. I just did it

Answer (score 0):

you need to check several things.

1. make sure your Search textfield working properly each time you type filter text and enter on it. i see your code pass nothing to server. ( data: {} here.)
2. check whether the you receiving filtered data from account_list.php ajax call.
3. try check on your query in account_list.php. seems your Search data should query with Account Name column. like.. ACOUNT_NAME like '%filter%'

you need to check the results on success block.

success: function(res) <- here. the "res"

additionally,

it would be better to add below success block for tracking errors. i assume that this case can be a result error or something unexpected processes on your query.

example :

```
error:function(e)
{  
              alert(e.responseText);  
}
```

Secondary, each time you success the ajax call you probably needs clearing "tableBody" table above. otherwise, it will stack previous data you searched.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is that you don't APPEND to the table. You're using a datatable. You want to do `$("#dataTable").dataTable().rows.add(["col1","col2",..., "colLast"]).draw();` and then you can search the table. DataTable doesn't search the rows IN the table, it searches the rows that you ADD to the table with its own method.

The draw is important. If you don't add the .`draw()` at the end, it won't actually show the changes that were done.

```
$('#dataTable').dataTable().rows.add([res[i]['account_id'],
                            res[i]['bvcsi_control'],
                            res[i]['account_name'],
                            res[i]['date_inspection'],
                            res[i]['date_report'],
                            res[i]['act_useof_prop'],
                            res[i]['landmark'],
                            res[i]['reg_owner'],     
                            lst]).draw();
```

This assumes your table has an id of "table"

Answer (score 0):

Datatables is extremely powerful - if you use the features it has, and don't try to build your own (which is sort of what you were trying to do.....)

Your HTML is OK (you don't need the 'id' in the tbody for datatables).

Your JS needs a lot of cleanup (and letting datatables do its job!)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var theTable = $("dataTable").dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            url: "../srtdash/php_functions/account_list.php"
            // this presumes you are returning a json list of info you want 
            // (since you see it in the first example, it looks like it is OK)
            // see https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html
        },
        responsive: true,  // if you want a responsive table
        "order": [0, 'desc'],  // make the order as you like (count starts at column 0!)
        "columns": [
            {data: 'account_id'},
            {data: "bvcsi_control"},
            {data: 'account_name'},
            {data: "date_inspection"},
            {data: 'date_report'},
            {data: 'act_useof_prop'},
            {data: 'landmark'},
            {data: 'reg_owner'},
            {data: 'status'}
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                // here is where you do your 'button' stuff (or anything you want to change in the table....)
                // 'data' is the info of the column
                render: function (data, type, row) {
                    var lst;
                    if (data === 1 ){
                       lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-primary">Pending</a></h4>';
                    }else if (data === 2 ){
                        lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-secondary">For Approval</a></h4>';
                    }else if (data === 3 ) {
                         lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-success">For CAD</a></h4>';
                    }else if (data === 4 ){
                         lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-danger">For Appraisal</a></h4>';
                    }else if (data === 5 ){
                         lst = '<h4><a href="#" class="badge badge-info">Release</a></h4>';
                    }                        
                    return data;
                },
                targets: [8] // changes Status to a button
            }
        ]
    })
});
```

There's some other cleanup I would do (for example, not duplicating the HTML in the 'lst' lines), though this should get you going - and using datatables like it 'should' be used (utilizing its power to do the work for you!)